# Formatting using loop

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Currently at the moment I am able display text from a loop and above the text a red circle displays using the `i class` and code below:

```
<div id="testwrap"> 
@foreach (mainnav mainnav in @Model)
{
    if (mainnav.HasSideNav == 0)
    {
    <a style="color:red" href='@Url.Action("Content", new { id = mainnav.contentID })' class="ajax2">@mainnav.DisplayLabel</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center feature">
        <i class="fa fa-tablet iconred"></i> 
    <a style="color:blue" href='@Url.Action("SideNavLevel1", new { id = mainnav.MNavSubID })' class="ajax2">@mainnav.DisplayLabel</a>
    </div>
    }
}
 </div>
```

My aim is it to have the icon be blue, green, yellow, orange etc...

I have tried to add in a counter but it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me to add the loop/ counter in to change where is says iconred to iconblue etc...?

Comment: When do you want red, orange or blue ?

Comment: I have 4 circles that appear so it should be iconred, iconblue, iconyellow, icongreen. The problem is that I am using a loop to get this data back from a table and it comes back as 4 links on one line which is why I am getting just four red circles.

Comment: So the fifth item will be again red ?

Comment: There will only ever be 4 circles.

Comment: So your collection(`@Model) will have only 4 items ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep your colors in an array and use that along with a counter.

```
@{
    var counter = 0;
    string[] colors = new string[] { "red", "blue", "orange","green" };
}

<div id="testwrap">

    @foreach (var mainnav in YourCollection)
    {
        if (mainnav.HasSideNav == 0)
        {
            <a style="color: red" href='#' class="ajax2">@mainnav.DisplayLabel</a>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center feature">
                <i class="fa fa-tablet icon@(colors[counter])"></i>
                <a style="color: blue" href='#' class="ajax2">@mainnav.DisplayLabel</a>
            </div>
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter == 4)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }    
    }
</div>
```

If you have more than 4 items in your collection, the fifth item will be again red and so on.

Comment: Thank you, I have added in the counter code and icon@(colors[counter] and it works :)